# Adding redux to react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i'm currently working on an app using react-native for the first time,
but i'm struggling to add redux.
i get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined` and i don't know how to fix it.
this my code :

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./home";


import { store } from "./redux/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
/* @flow */

import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Home />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

store.js :

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";

import reducer from "./reducer";

const middlewares = [logger];

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));

export default store;
```

reducer.js :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import mapReducer from "../redux/maps/maps-reducer";


export default combineReducers({
  map: mapReducer
});
```

maps-action.js:

```
import MAPSActionTypes from './maps-action-types';

export const currentlocation = () => ({
    console.log(${location});
    type : MAPSActionTypes.GET_CURRENT_LOCATION
});
```

maps-reducer.js:

```
import MAPSActionTypes from "./mapsactiontypes";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  location: {}
};

const mapReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MAPSActionTypes.GET_CURRENT_LOCATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        location: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default mapReducer;
```

home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';



import {connect} from 'react-redux'


const Home = (props) => {

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>welcome</Text>
        <Text>{props.location}</Text>
      </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  }
});


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    location: state.map.location
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

i'm all ears from more clarification or more details.
i will be very thankful if there's anyone who can help me to fix that problem.

Comment: Maybe you could show a bit more detailed stacktrace and also how do you connect the component you're calling redux action from?

Comment: @Clarity i edited the post , can u check it now ?

Comment: Code looks ok, can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Instead of this `location: state.map.location` try this `location: state.location`. You don't have `map` variable in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you `export default` in `store.js` file.

```
export default store;
```

But in `App` you `import` it with `{}`. So the `store` you imported is `undefined`.

```
import { store } from "./redux/store";
```

The correct import is

```
import store from "./redux/store";
```